# wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor on fork + pipe + execlp

Tags: c, linux

I know this is a simple exercise but I'm having troubles with it.  I'm trying to emulate:

```
grep arg1 arg2 | wc -l
```

I'm getting the following error: "wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor when executing". This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) usage();
    int pd[2]; //Pipe descriptor
    pipe(pd);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) perror("Something failed on trying to create a child process!\n");
    else if (pid == 0) { //Child
        dup2(pd[1], 0);
        close(pd[0]);
        close(pd[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *)NULL);
    } else { //Parent
        dup2(pd[0], 1);
        close(pd[0]);
        close(pd[1]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", argv[1], argv[2], (char *)NULL);
    }
}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't see an emulation, but you just run the two programs.

Comment: yah, he isnt talking about actually trying to do emulation, he is trying to write a program that emulates the BEHAVIOR of another program, ie write a c program that counts lines matching grep pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
else if (pid == 0) { //Child
    dup2(pd[1], 0);
    close(pd[0]);
    close(pd[1]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *)NULL);
}
```

You need:

```
else if (pid == 0) { //Child
    dup2(pd[0], 0); 
    close(pd[0]);
    close(pd[1]);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *)NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute 'wc'\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

The crucial change is the `dup2()`; your code copies the write end of the pipe to the child's standard input , which is not a recipe for happiness.  The revised code copies the read end of the pipe to the child's standard input.  It's easy enough to remember which is which: stdin is file descriptor 0 and pipe descriptor 0 of the pair is the input descriptor (read end of the pipe), while stdout is file descriptor 1 and pipe descriptor 1 of the pair is the output descriptor (write end of the pipe).

You need the converse change in the 'parent' code.

The error arises when `wc` tries to read from a file descriptor that's only open for writing.

Note that if `execlp()` — or any other member of the `exec*()` family of functions — returns, it failed.  It is important to deal with that error, usually by reporting a problem on standard error and exiting.  It is seldom correct to have no statement after the `exec*()` operation.

Comment: But with dup2(pd[1], 0) we are copying pipe output chanel on my input chanel, that is what I want no? I want to read from the pipe's output.

Comment: No; the child process wants to read from the read end of the pipe; the parent wants to write to the write end of the pipe.  That way, you have data flowing from the parent to the child.  You have it back-to-front.

Comment: Oh that's right! What a mistake! Thank you both so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you trying to replicate the terminal command of "wc -l | grep something something".

The problem is that you are not providing input to wc. wc -l command requires an input for which it should count its lines. Try something like:

```
execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", "somefile.txt", (char *)NULL);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what I'm trying to replicate!, I'm trying to "grep word file | wc -l" that should give me the number of instances of the word 'word' in the file 'file'.
argv[1] = word and argv[2] = file